# Defining antlr rule for identifiers with one character

Tags: antlr

i like to define a very simple rule, which should represent identifiers. This works quite well for identifiers which are longer than one characters, but for identifiers with exactly one character I get a MismatchedTokenException(64!=45). This is the rule:

ID  :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
    ;

What is wrong with that?

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `ID : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+ ;`

Comment: You should show your whole grammar, right now there's not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: I agree with Aivar.  Probably show your tokens file, especailly what is 64 and 45.  Oh yeah, probably your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely right, the rule on its own is fine, but I figured out that a lot in ANTLR depends on the order of rules. I had another rule before, which did already match the ID rule. Finally it makes sense, because the Lexer cannot decide which rule to take.

Thanks!

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, please accept your own answer to get the question out of everyone's way.

Comment: Thanks, I simply shifted my ID rule and placed it after the string literals but before my URI rule, it solved the issue.